# I am trying to use a proxy through Java but keep getting "Use getHelp to get to the guidelines about reporter tool.Report"

Tags: java, proxy

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=" my host" -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -jar Reporter.jar
```

I am new to this so i dont know what i am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is not complete. You need to add some additional parameters after 
-jar Reporter.jar.

For example:

```
$java -Dhttp.proxyHost=" my host" -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -jar Reporter.jar$
p=Reporter.properties Sales.getReport 123456, Sales, Summary, Daily, 
20171004
```